# Android App Keeps Stopping - On Launch Error

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a problem with a Xamarin forms application. When I execute the forms app, I get the message that the app has stopped.

You can see it in this image:

[image]

Comment: There is absolutely no useful information here that we could use to help you.  You need to do some basic debugging to narrow down the cause of the problem - look at the app logs, instrument your app, use the interactive debugger, etc.

Comment: how i can use the interactive debugger

Comment: Are you using Visual studio? If then you should be able to run the app from there and see the Exception you are getting and post that here.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/debugging?view=vsmac-2019

Comment: Nirmal Subedi Yes Visual studio

Comment: Look through the Device Logs to see why your application is stopping - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/debugging/android-debug-log?tabs=windows

Comment: @SADIOMANE You can see the Output window in Visual Studio first to check what problem is. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/output-window?view=vs-2019

Comment: Try to see more details by using logcat.

Install your app and check ApplicationOutput window.
If there is no useful information (happens a lot to me) then open a terminal and run logcat by: 

adb logcat | grep Exception

This will show all Exceptions happening on the device. Run the app again, the cause of your crash should now appear in terminal.
Then post the Exception log here.

Comment: @SADIOMANE Hi, you can share the project , I will check it  :)